# how to create subject schedules using vb.net and crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

[i want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7hKf.jpg)

[This is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx9fx.jpg)

this is my code
i use DataSet to make this

```
Private Sub BtnCetakPerKelas_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCetakPerKelas.Click
        Try
            If CboSemester.Text = String.Empty Then
                MessageBox.Show("Pilih semester")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    Try
        Try
            query = "Select TA, Kelas, Semester From TblJadwal_Detail where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' order by kelas"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabel = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabel)


            Dim tabel1 As New DataTable
            tabel.Columns.Add(3)
            tabel.Columns(3).ColumnName = "Sesi"
            For i = 0 To 7
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(3) = i + 1
            Next

            'senin
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Senin'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim tabels As New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(4)
            tabel.Columns(4).ColumnName = "Senin"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(4) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            'selasa
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Selasa'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabels = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(5)
            tabel.Columns(5).ColumnName = "Selasa"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(5) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            'Rabu
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Rabu'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabels = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(6)
            tabel.Columns(6).ColumnName = "Rabu"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(6) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            'kamis
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Kamis'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabels = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(7)
            tabel.Columns(7).ColumnName = "Kamis"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(7) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            'Jumat
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Jumat'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabels = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(8)
            tabel.Columns(8).ColumnName = "Jumat"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(8) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            'sabtu
            query = "Select MataPelajaran.MP From TblJadwal_Detail inner join MataPelajaran On TblJadwal_Detail.KodeMP = MataPelajaran.KodeMP where TA = '" & TxtTA.Text & "' and TblJadwal_Detail.Semester = '" & _
                CboSemester.Text & "' and Hari = 'Sabtu'"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            tabels = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(tabels)
            tabel.Columns.Add(9)
            tabel.Columns(9).ColumnName = "Sabtu"
            For i = 0 To tabels.Rows.Count - 1
                tabel.Rows.Add(i)
                tabel.Rows(i)(9) = tabels.Rows(i)(0)
            Next

            Dim cr As New cetakjadwalkelas
            Dim pr As New Vw1

            cr.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(tabel)


            pr.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
            pr.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            pr.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure all of this code is necessary for us to be able to help you?

Comment: You'd be better off if you export your data to excel.  Formatting would be a lot easier.